# Develop a game using android or web technologies?

Tags: android, html5-canvas, game-engine

I haven't created a game before but I have a 2d-game on my mind that I wanted to develop. Though I am quite familiar with using javascript and aware of html5's canvas, I am not aware of the performance impact of creating using this tech over an android game. I am also aware about Chrome App and it's ability to work offline.

1. What will be guide in choosing between the two (advantage, disadvantage)?
2. Can the responsive feature of web be applied on a game?

Imagine my game as cut the rope for example...

Answer (score 0):

Considering the performance and usability between browser and android, in your case there is no difference.

It comes down to what you are planning to achieve by creating this game of yours. Whether you are planning to make a fortune this way or not.

Advantages of browser games are:

1. easier to create (considering you know how to program in javascript)
2. web browser is more common these days than android therefore the accessability of such game is bigger
3. for someone to play your game, it is enough to type the correct web address( and this is also the biggest problem for you to overcome, either you are using some existing game platform such as facebook, or you have other means of how to advertise your web page, or you are doomed)

Advantages of android games:

1. without proper advertisement, it is easier to get some people play your game
2. programming 3D graphics for android is easier than programming in WebGL (though this is arguable considering Three.js)